# Geolocation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, geolocation

I have a client with a site that shows a different content based on the user country (england, australia or other). I tried several plugins that allow to "convert" the ip to the country (right now I'm using Visitor Country, I also tried ip-to-country and World Flags and I think one more I can't recall).

When I check through vpn everything seem to work fine, but the client - who travel a lot - almost always sees the wrong content (for instance when he was in the uk he saw the $ instead of the pound symbol). He tried from several computers.

Regarding the code it's pretty simple. Right now when the content need to be different I usually use:

```
if($VisitorCountry->GetName()=='United Kingdom') {do stuff}
else if($VisitorCountry->GetName()=='Australia') {do other stuff}
else {do some other stuff}
```

Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 1):

Probably to late for OP but may answer question for others.

If it works for you but not for your client using a variety of different computers then it is probably a caching plugin issue.

**Cause of problem** (your example):  if the "first" visitor to the page was from the US, the caching plugin takes a snapshot of the page with your dollar symbols.  When your client views the page in the UK the caching plugin/WP ignores PHP code and serves the previously built snapshot (with dollars not pounds).

**Why YOUR testing failed to identify problems:** Not intended as a criticism. (I'm the author of the Category Country Aware plugin just listed on wordpress.org. Even knowingly testing my plugin with caching the "previously logged on" gotcha (below) puzzled me.)

If you are logged into the site (as any user) or were PREVIOUSLY logged in with the same browser then many of the WP caching plugins will serve you a newly generated UNcached page. The code to dynamically generate the currency symbol for your location will have run.  Your client however has used computers in hotels/internet cafes that have never been logged in to the site so he sees the cached page.

I've written **more about this including HOW to test** here: http://wptest.means.us.com/2014/11/caching-and-geoLocation/

**Fixing country location/caching conflicts:**

Most major caching plugins allow you to identify pages that should not be cached.  This is fine if only a few pages have custom content or when country relevant sidebar widgets are only displayed for a single category with a small number of posts. But if you are having to disable caching for masses of pages the benefits of using a caching plugin become minimal.

Some caching plugins allow you to write extensions to modify their caching behaviour. I'm final testing extensions to Supercache and ZenCache so they  still cache all pages but serve the correct content to visitors from different countries. I'll add these to my site shortly. You may find you can write equivalent extensions for other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this? Not sure if it will work for your specific use case though.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgeocode/

Comment: I tried several plugin but I don't think I know this one so I'll give it a try. The thing is I can't really check because, as I mentioned in my post, I can only check with VPN and I always see the right data...